Remote Desktop Connection closes almost immediately when trying to connect to Debian via WSL
Hello everyone,
I'm facing intermittent issues with accessing my Linux server from a Windows 10 PC using XRDP. Here are the details:

Linux Distribution: Debian 12
XRDP Version: 0.9.21
Desktop Environment: Windows

Logs from systemctl status xrdp:
● xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-05-29 13:41:25 +01; 2h 29min ago
Docs: man:xrdp(8)
man:xrdp.ini(5)
Process: 2208 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/xrdp/socksetup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 2216 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 2217 (xrdp)
Tasks: 1 (limit: 4630)
Memory: 904.0K
CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
└─2217 /usr/sbin/xrdp
May 29 16:06:26 DESKTOP-BT9EVUK xrdp[2670]: [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
May 29 16:06:26 DESKTOP-BT9EVUK xrdp[2670]: [INFO ] sesman connect ok
May 29 16:06:26 DESKTOP-BT9EVUK xrdp[2670]: [INFO ] sending login info to session manager. Please wait...
May 29 16:06:26 DESKTOP-BT9EVUK xrdp[2670]: [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for user osama on display 11
May 29 16:06:26 DESKTOP-BT9EVUK xrdp[2670]: [INFO ] login successful for user osama on display 11
May 29 16:06:26 DESKTOP-BT9EVUK xrdp[2670]: [INFO ] loaded module 'libxup.so' ok, interface size 10296, version 4
May 29 16:06:27 DESKTOP-BT9EVUK xrdp[2670]: [INFO ] started connecting
May 29 16:06:27 DESKTOP-BT9EVUK xrdp[2670]: [INFO ] lib_mod_connect: connecting via UNIX socket
May 29 16:06:27 DESKTOP-BT9EVUK xrdp[2670]: [INFO ] lib_mod_log_peer: xrdp_pid=2670 connected to X11rdp_pid=2673 X11rdp>
May 29 16:06:27 DESKTOP-BT9EVUK xrdp[2670]: [INFO ] connected ok
i have tried everything on the web but no progress let me know if you need more info
thanks in advance
